# Installing VS2012 (which includes MVC4) breaks existing ASP.NET MVC 3 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

After installing VS2012 and hereby MVC 4, I have an MVC3 application which now fails with the following runtime error:

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 System.Web.Razor.Parser.CSharpCodeParser.get_RazorKeywords()'.

If I create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project in VS2010 it works ok with razors views. Has anybody else experienced similar issues?

Comment: 4.5 is an in-place upgrade from 4.0... fun times.

Comment: Do you apgrade your application to 4.5 .net framework?

Comment: In my web.config I noticed this block which I have now commented out, and now this error does not happen anymore:
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: @ssn - Which Web.config file did you find that line in?  Is it in the one in the system's Framework directory, ~/Web.config in an existing application, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 26):

@Levi it was in Web.config in the root of the project.

In my web.config I noticed this block which I have now commented out, and now this error does not happen anymore:

```
<dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"   
                      culture="neutral" /> 
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: This fixed our issue.

Comment: This caused a compliler warning so I changed it to force version 1.0   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>

Answer (score 9):

This is documented behavior. VS2012 installs MVC4.
Please read section "Installing ASP.NET MVC 4  breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM applications" from link 
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815

The specific cause of the error is that the project templates in ASP.NET MVC 3 did not specify which version of Razor to use, so by default it picks up the newest version of Razor, even though MVC 3 is compatible only with Razor v1.

- MVC 3 is compatible with only Razor v1
- MVC 4 is compatible with only Razor v2

So, the fix, as described in the MVC4 Release Notes, is to change the MVC 3 app's web.config file to use Razor v1.

All new project templates (including MVC3) will have this set correctly. Only older apps don't have this setting.

Comment: You can use Razor 2 with MVC 3: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2012/04/28/using-razor-v2-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an old project using **MVC 3** in Visual Studio 2015.

For some reason, **Razor v2** was installed and I had the error described by the OP:

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 System.Web.Razor.Parser.CSharpCodeParser.get_RazorKeywords()'.

At first, I tried the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12079223/771496) and I commented a couple of lines in my `Web.Config`. But it created this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Then, I saw [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12596405/771496) on this post about a *possible* incompatibility between MVC 3 and Razor v2. I simply updated *ASP.NET MVC* with the following command in the *Package Manager Console* :

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

... and everything started to work again!

Answer (score 0):

In general Mvc3 is not supported after VS2010,I use VS2010SP1 btw.
You may make it work but it will bite you in the end.
So i reccomend choosing matching VS and MVC versions(check the official microsoft site for the matchings)